# What is the maximum level for assassins?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Assassin's Creed: Revelations, what is the highest level my assassins can reach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

15 for den masters.

I think if they are not den master, it's 10.

Comment: If they aren't assigned to a den, they stop at 10, but continue to gain XP. It seems, from my experience, that when a rank 10 hits XP cap (15500), they're almost as effective as the Master Assassins.

Comment: Whatever it is, they are pretty darn effective by that level!